# Obtaining modifier key pressed in CGEvent tap

Tags: events, macos, core-graphics

Having setup an event tap, I'm not able to identify what modifier key was pressed given a CGEvent.

```
 CGEventFlags flagsP;

 flagsP=CGEventGetFlags(event);

 NSLog(@"flags: 0x%llX",flagsP);
 NSLog(@"stored: 0x%llX",kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);

 if (flagsP==kCGEventFlagMaskCommand) {
       NSLog(@"command pressed");
    }
```

Given the above snippet, the first NSLog returns a different value from the second NSLog. No surprise that the conditional is never triggered when the command modifier key is pressed.

I need to identify whether command, alternate, option, control or shift are pressed for a given CGEvent. First though, I need help to understand why the above isn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are bit masks, which will be bitwise-ORed together into the value you receive from `CGEventGetFlags` (or pass when creating an event yourself).

You can't test equality here because no single bit mask will be equal to a combination of multiple bit masks. You need to test equality of a single bit.

To extract a single bit mask's value from a combined bit mask, use the bitwise-AND (`&`) operator. Then, compare that to the single bit mask you're interested in:

```
BOOL commandKeyIsPressed = (flagsP & kCGEventFlagMaskCommand) == kCGEventFlagMaskCommand;
```

Why both?

The `&` expression evaluates to the same type as its operands, which is `CGEventFlags` in this case, which may not fit in the size of a `BOOL`, which is a `signed char`. The `==` expression resolves that to 1 or 0, which is all that will fit in a `BOOL`.

Other solutions to that problem include negating the value twice (`!!`) and declaring the variable as `bool` or `_Bool` rather than `Boolean` or `BOOL`. C99's `_Bool` type (synonymized to `bool` when you include stdbool.h) forces its value to be either 1 or 0, just as the `==` and `!!` solutions do.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. That explains it extremely well and solves my problem.

Comment: Great thanks, also do you know if there is a way to check if any modifier is being pressed? Or would I have to explicitly check like this for each one?

Comment: I did this but don't know if it is the best/cleanest way?
`BOOL isModifierPressed = (flags & (kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate | kCGEventFlagMaskCommand | kCGEventFlagMaskControl | kCGEventFlagMaskShift)) > 0;
`

Comment: @infensus: It isn't. `> 0` is wrong here, since you mean not to arithmetically compare a number; you mean to test a (metaphorical) bank of switches. If you want to know whether any of the switches (bits) are on, that is the logical negation of whether all of them are off, so you want to compare whether `flags & (…)` is *not equal to* 0 using `!=`. If you want to know whether *all* of those specific switches are on, compare `flags & (…)` to the same set of flags using `==`.